# mplayer: relocation error

Tags: opensuse, mplayer

I am using OpenSUSE and after a recent update, my `mplayer` is not working properly. Whenever I play a video, I am getting the following error:

```
mplayer: relocation error: /usr/lib64/libavformat.so.57: symbol avpriv_dict_set_timestamp, version LIBAVUTIL_55 not defined in file libavutil.so.55 with link time reference
```

Comment: Version of openSUSE? , + to correctly working media players you need mplayer ith enabled patented code which is in packman repository https://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories#Packman

Comment: Sorry for the late response. openSUSE Version is 42.1. I download it from Packman repository only.

Answer (score 0):

Change all the url's repos from 42.1 to 42.2

http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/oss/

And docu for dist upgrade : https://en.opensuse.org/Upgrade part Command line

Add packman in repos. See https://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories#Packman

http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/

Make "zypper dup"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate that. My current openSUSE version is 42.1. By doing zypper dup will upgrade my distro version to 42.2 right?

Comment: @Abmuthu by changing all links in `/etc/zypp/repos.d/*.repo` files and after this `zypper dup`

Comment: @mimi.vx.Thank you! I get it. Is there a way I can solve this problem without upgrading to 42.2? I want to stay in 42.1 itself.